# Different content for different panel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show different contents depending on the selected link, because for now all links take the same class which have only one content. I don't know how to add another div for another link using the same class or should I create a different class of each div/link ?

https://jsfiddle.net/sx6L93k1/16/

```js
// Reveal & Close Panels
var revealPanel = function(buttonReveal, panel, buttonClose) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Reveal panel 
    $(buttonReveal).on('click', function() {
      $(panel).addClass('expanded');
      console.log('hidefor-' + panel);
      $(".content").addClass('hidefor-' + panel.substr(1));
      $(".ip").addClass('hidefor-' + panel.substr(1));
    });

    // Close panel
    $(buttonClose).on('click', function() {
      $(panel).removeClass('expanded');
      $(".content").removeClass('hidefor-panel-up');
      $(".ip").removeClass('hidefor-panel-up');
    });

    // ESC to close Panel
    $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $(panel).removeClass('expanded');
        $(".content").removeClass('hidefor-panel-up');
        $(".ip").removeClass('hidefor-panel-up');
      }
    });
  });
}

revealPanel('.reveal-up', '.panel-up', '.close');
revealPanel('.reveal-left', '.panel-left', '.close');


// Reveal Panel with Shortcuts
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 76) {
      console.log(e.keyCode);
      $('.panel-left').addClass('expanded');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 82) {
      $('.panel-up').addClass('expanded');
      $(".content").addClass('hidefor-panel-up');
      $(".ip").addClass('hidefor-panel-up');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  padding: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 10%;
}

.content.hidefor-panel-up {
  bottom: 20%;
  transform: scale(0.95);
  opacity: 0;
}

.ip {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: -5;
  position: absolute;
}

.ip.hidefor-panel-up {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 10%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  background: #06113E;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

code {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background: #efefef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

ul {
  margin: 30px 40px;
}

li {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.panel {
  padding: 20px;
}

.panel-content {
  position: relative;
  /*background: #efefef;*/
  padding: 30px 50px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.panel-content .close {
  line-height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  content: "✖";
}

.panel-content .close:before {
  line-height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  content: "✖";
}

.panel-left {
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #eeeeee;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  left: -100%;
  width: 45%;
}

.panel-left.expanded {
  left: 0;
}

.panel-up {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  bottom: -20%;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel-up.expanded {
  bottom: 0;
}

.reveal-left {
  float: left;
}

.reveal-up {
  float: right;
}

.nav {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 10px;
  width: 90%;
}

.nav button {
  padding: 4px 6px;
}

.nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #222;
}

.bottom {
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav" style="color:white;z-index:99999999;position:absolute;">

  <a style="color:white;" href="#" class="reveal-up">First Panel</a>
  <br>
  <a style="color:white;" href="#" class="reveal-up">Second panel</a>
</div>

<div class="panel-up">
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="close"></div>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 30px; color:white;">up Panel</p>
    <div class="bottom">
      Some content here.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<img class="ip" style="opacity:1; z-index:-5; position:absolute; transform: scale(1.2)" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431440869543-efaf3388c585?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80">
<div class="content" style="color:white">

  <h2 style="margin-top:10px;">Side Panels Test</h2>
  <p>This is a prototype test to create two side panels that are controlled by CSS in terms of their animation. Click either the "Left Panel" or "Right Panel" buttons to reveal the panel. Then click on the <code>✖</code> close or use the keyboard shortcuts
    as seen below:</p>
  <ul>
    <li><code>ESC</code> - Close all windows</li>
    <li><code>L</code> - Open Right panel</li>
    <li><code>R</code> - Open Left panel</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```